# IllegalArgumentException when passing navigation outcome string to method expression

Tags: jsf, navigation, composite-component, illegalargumentexception, methodexpression

I am calling this xhtml file

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:cc="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite">

<!-- OPTIONAL INTERFACE -->
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="searchAction"
                  default="#{searchController.searchAuthors(compAuthorController.completeAuthorList)}"/>
</cc:interface>

<!-- IMPLEMENTATION -->
<cc:implementation>
    <h:form>
        <h:outputText id="error" value="#{searchController.errorText}"/><br/>
        <h:inputText id="searchText" styleClass="searchBox" size="75"
                     value="#{searchController.searchText}"/>
        <h:commandButton id="searchButton" value="SEARCH"
                         action="#{cc.attrs.searchAction}"/>
    </h:form>
</cc:implementation>

</html>
```

from a template using `<util:search id="searchAuthor"/>` i have the search button an everything but when i try to run it i got **javax.el.ELException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert example04_01a of type class java.lang.String to class javax.el.MethodExpression** for sake of this thread the method `searchController.searchAuthors` only return a string, which is a xhtml page

```
public String searchAuthors(List<Author> list){
    return "example04_01a";
}
```

log:

```
Warning:   #{cc.attrs.searchAction}: javax.el.ELException:  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert example04_01a of type class java.lang.String to class javax.el.MethodExpression
javax.faces.FacesException: #{cc.attrs.searchAction}: javax.el.ELException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert example04_01a of type class java.lang.String to class javax.el.MethodExpression
at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: javax.el.ELException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert example04_01a of type class java.lang.String to class javax.el.MethodExpression
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
... 35 more
Caused by: javax.el.ELException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert example04_01a of type class java.lang.String to class javax.el.MethodExpression
at com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl.coerceToType(ExpressionFactoryImpl.java:87)
at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingExpressionFactory.coerceToType(ForwardingExpressionFactory.java:38)
at javax.el.ELContext.convertToType(ELContext.java:478)
at com.sun.el.lang.EvaluationContext.convertToType(EvaluationContext.java:166)
at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:229)
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ContextualCompositeValueExpression.getValue(ContextualCompositeValueExpression.java:158)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.TagAttributeImpl$AttributeLookupMethodExpression.invoke(TagAttributeImpl.java:469)
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert example04_01a of type class java.lang.String to class javax.el.MethodExpression
at com.sun.el.lang.ELSupport.coerceToType(ELSupport.java:424)
at com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl.coerceToType(ExpressionFactoryImpl.java:85)
... 45 more

FATAL:   JSF1073: javax.faces.FacesException caught during processing of    INVOKE_APPLICATION 5 : UIComponent-ClientId=, Message=#{cc.attrs.searchAction}: javax.el.ELException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert example04_01a of type class java.lang.String to class javax.el.MethodExpression
FATAL:   #{cc.attrs.searchAction}: javax.el.ELException:   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert example04_01a of type class java.lang.String to class javax.el.MethodExpression
javax.faces.FacesException: #{cc.attrs.searchAction}: javax.el.ELException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert example04_01a of type class java.lang.String to class javax.el.MethodExpression
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:89)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: #{cc.attrs.searchAction}: javax.el.ELException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert example04_01a of type class java.lang.String to class javax.el.MethodExpression
at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
... 31 more
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: javax.el.ELException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert example04_01a of type class java.lang.String to class javax.el.MethodExpression
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
... 35 more
Caused by: javax.el.ELException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert example04_01a of type class java.lang.String to class javax.el.MethodExpression
at com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl.coerceToType(ExpressionFactoryImpl.java:87)
at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingExpressionFactory.coerceToType(ForwardingExpressionFactory.java:38)
at javax.el.ELContext.convertToType(ELContext.java:478)
at com.sun.el.lang.EvaluationContext.convertToType(EvaluationContext.java:166)
at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:229)
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ContextualCompositeValueExpression.getValue(ContextualCompositeValueExpression.java:158)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.TagAttributeImpl$AttributeLookupMethodExpression.invoke(TagAttributeImpl.java:469)
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert example04_01a of type class java.lang.String to class javax.el.MethodExpression
at com.sun.el.lang.ELSupport.coerceToType(ELSupport.java:424)
at    com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl.coerceToType(ExpressionFactoryImpl.java:85)
... 45 more
```

Comment: try using method-signature in cc:attribute

Comment: That solved it thanks